# Temporarily Overriding a Binding ReceiveTimeOut on the Server Side in WCF

Tags: wcf, timeout

I have created a service which uses WCF for communication.  Very basic.  The server side is set up to listen like this where IEdWCF is my service contract which calls various methods on the server, ntb is a NetBinding with a ReceiveTimeout set to 60 minutes, and strHostURL is on localhost:

Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEdWCF),
                    ntb,
                    new Uri(strHostURL));

The thing is that I have some items I want to send through but allow a longer processing time to (the client awaits a reply from the server and keeps getting dropped by the server)

I know on my client side I can extend the request by casting the channel as an IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing I'm doing with the client on the server.

Is this possible?  Is there some way to dynamically change the setting on the server binding?

Comment: If you mean the client setting the timeout on the server, no.  Would you really want to give clients the ability to fiddle with your service settings?

Comment: Absolutely not.  What I am trying to do is have the server look at an incoming request and - if it meets certain criteria - override the ReceiveTimeout that is set in the service config.  I don't want to globally increase the timeout.  Right now, the server is terminating the connection to the client throwing a socket error due to the server timing out during a specific operation.

Comment: @Jave - did you ever get somewhere with this?